# how to sort alphanumeric values in excel in a specific format i desire other than the one done by default

Tags: excel, sorting

i have certain values in the excel column as 1 6 5 2 3 1a 3b1 3b4 3b3 2c 2d. When this is sorted i get the result as 1 2 3 5 6 1a 2c 2d 3b1 3b3 3b4. But i am supposed to get it as 1 1a 2 2c 2d 3 3b1 3b3 3b4 5 6. How to get the desired result?

Comment: What have you tried?  I would suggest splitting the entries into two columns, and sorting by the numeric, and then the alpha.  There are plenty of examples in SO as to how to split this time of entry.  Another method would be to add leading zero's to the numbers and sort as text.

Comment: Another option would be to split each entry into single character values across the adjacent rows; then sort by each column from left to right

Answer (score 0):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** insert:

```
=A1 & CHAR(1)
```

and copy down.  Then sort cols **A** & **B** by **B**:

[image]

Afterwards, column **B** can be cleared.

Comment: A possible problem with both your solution, and my second suggestion in comments, is the sorting that results if there is an entry such as `10b8`.  It would appear second in those lists.  Not sure if that is what the OP wants.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  If the OP wants a different sort order, I will fix my answer.....good catch!